# Adding a No Results Found option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a script to autocomplete a search field. I am trying to add a "No Results Found" option when nothing is found with a hyperlink behind it. I am struggling to figure out how to add an else() to it to show the Text.

How do I add this script? Thank You.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
     $('#search').keyup(function(){
      $('#result').html('');
      $('#state').val('');
      var searchField = $('#search').val();
      var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
      $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(key, value){
        if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
        {
         $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"> '+value.name+'</li>');
        }
       });   
      });
     });

     $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
      var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
      $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
      $("#result").html('');
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a boolean in the loop to indicate one was found, then check the boolean after the loop.

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  var found = false;

  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1) {
      found = true;

      $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"> ' + value.name + '</li>');
    }
  });

  if (!found) {
    $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class">NOTHING FOUND</li>');
  }
});
```

---

Another option would be to `.filter()` the results before appending them. Then you could simply check the length of the filtered array (assuming it's an array).

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  var filtered = data.filter(function(value) {
    return value.name.search(expression) != -1 ||
           value.location.search(expression) != -1;
  });

  var res = $('#result');

  if (filtered.length) {
    filtered.forEach(function(value) {
      res.append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"> ' + value.name + '</li>');
    });
  } else {
    res.append('<li class="list-group-item link-class">NOTHING FOUND</li>');
  }
});
```

---

And expanding on that, I think I'd actually map the strings to an array, and do a single append.

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  var liHTML = data.filter(function(value) {
    return value.name.search(expression) != -1 ||
           value.location.search(expression) != -1;
  }).map(function(value) {
     return '<li class="list-group-item link-class"> ' + value.name + '</li>';
  });

  if (!liHTML.length)
    liHTML.push('<li class="list-group-item link-class">NOTHING FOUND</li>');

  $('#result').append(liHTML.join(""));
});
```

Comment: I have used your boolean approach, I have tried to add the hyperlink with a simple href however this isn't working! Do you have any pointers?

Comment: @tbowden: You mean you still get an empty list? I don't see how that would be possible. Any errors in the developer console? And what hyperlinks are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry - Yes it shows up and works! I am trying to add a hyperlink to the text "Nothing Found".

Comment: I would prefer the last version as this will change the DOM only once instead of once for every item that matches the search expression.

Comment: @tbowden: Oh I see, the hyperlink would just be like regular HTML. Not sure where the issue would be without seeing your code.

Comment: @Andreas: Yep, me too.

Comment: This is what I have attempted: liHTML.push('<li href="https://www.google.com" class="list-group-item link-class">NOTHING FOUND</li>');

Comment: I have implemented the last version.

Comment: @tbowden: You can't add `href` to any element to make it a link. That's (mostly) just for `<a>` elements, so nest an `<a>` inside the `<li>`

Comment: ...like `'<li class="list-group-item link-class"><a  href="google.com">NOTHING FOUND</a></li>'`

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it helped.

Comment: Quick question... Currently when the button is clicked it fills the box then goes to the webpage. Is it easy to set it to go straight to the page - rather then fill the box first?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Probably best to just start another question if you can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you get an (apparently) static JSON value each time, so I cached that along with some other stuff.  Note that if the resulting data are NOT static you  probably want to throttle the keyup for fast key people.

It would have helped to see a snip of the actual JSON to test with but this should work.

- Use `let` to avoid global creep
- cached selectors to avoid DOM traversing
- use recommended document ready handler form
- got value(s) once from JSON (my assumption it is static but appears so
- added change even also for pasted text into field (or other code changing it like testing - note you DO that in the click handler there!
- use `.remove()` for children, perhaps faster, test this with max real data
- add `a` to no results, fix this to proper place/href

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  // cache selectors
  let result = $('#result');
  let state = $('#state');
  let search = $('#search');
  // create empty item
  let resultItem = $('<li class="list-group-item link-class"></li>');
  // create no results from empty item, COULD be dynamic `href` if needed
  let noResultItem = resultItem.clone().html('<a href="#somewhere">No Results</a>');
  // We might not need to get this every time? cache it
  let dataHold = {}; // empty holder
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    dataHold = data;
  });
  // change event also for paste etc users.
  search.on('keyup change', function() {
    // might be faster than .html(''). test this assumption
    result.children().remove();
    state.val('');// not sure what this is for or what sets it
    let searchField = search.val();
    let expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    // COULD cache the found results set IF it is large and append once
    $.each(dataHold, function(key, value) {
      if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1) {
        result.append(resultItem.clone().text(value.name));
      }
    });
    // no match? use empty
    if (!result.children().length) {
      noResultItem.appendTo(result);
    }
  });
  // do we want the class 'li.list-group-item' also?
  result.on('click', 'li', function() {
    let click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
    search.val($.trim(click_text[0]));
    result.children().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Search: <input id="search" type="text" /></label>
<label>State: <input id="state" type="text" value="i do no  know" /></label>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```